# Redirect subdomain to subfolder except www

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I need to redirect every *.example.com to other domain except www.example.com and example.com which I need to give index.php file...

I try:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www|)\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://app.example.com/%1/$1 [P,NC,QSA]


</IfModule>
```

but won't work - any subdomain redirect to index.php 
How to solve my problem?

**UPDATE**

I solve the problem with this code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(\w+)\.exampe\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}:%1 !^/([^/]+)/([^:]*):\1
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://app.example.com/m/%1/$1 [L,NC,QSA]


</IfModule>
```

but now browser clear my subdomain etc. `london.example.com` and show me `app.example.com/m/london` ... How can I keep my subdomain in the browser bar?

Comment: order is important! put the last rewritecond after the rewritebase

Comment: and change the rewrite flag to [R,QSA,L], redirect / append query string / last rule to proceed

Comment: I write this and works well: <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(\w+)\.example\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}:%1 !^/([^/]+)/([^:]*):\1
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://app.example.com/m/%1/$1 [L,NC,QSA]


</IfModule>   BUT BROWSER CLEAR SUBDOMAIN NAME... IS THERE A CHANGE A SUBDMAIN TO STAY HERE and not change with app.example.com ?

Comment: what do you mean? please update your question and not post code on comment

Comment: I UPDATE my question, please see above

Comment: @Ben Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: so you want to redirect `london.example.com` to `london.example.com/m/london` right, and the rule apply to all subdomain except `www.example.com` and `example.com`?

Comment: Yes. But user need to see subdonain when they looking  at app.example.com/m/subdomain

Answer (score 0):

The [`[P]` flag](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_p) should be used:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^((www|app)\.)?example\.com
# check if the host is not app.example.com www.example.com example.com

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(\w+)\.example\.com [NC]
# check if the host is subdomain of example.com

RewriteRule ^(.*) http://app.example.com/m/%1/$1 [QSA,P]
# proxy the request to http://app.example.com/%1/$1
# %1 is the back reference to the grouped part (\w+)
# $1 is the back reference to the grouped part (.*)
```

Comment: hm, NO, won't work... maybe the problem is because example.com (WP) and app.example.com are not at the same IP address? Also is it possible to do that if both are not at the same IP address?

Comment: should have other `RewriteRule` conflict

Comment: no, there is no conflict I think ... Isnt different IP address problem ?

Comment: are they host in the same server? different IP address should not be a problem